# How can I update Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am pretty new using Ubuntu and I am using Visual Studio Code for scripting. I have the 1.64.2 version and everyday the computer shows me an alert inviting me to update to a new version. When I click to do it, starts a download of an .exe file (is the Window version). Can anybody help me to get the update in Ubuntu?.
Thaks a lot

Comment: It should be updated with the rest of your packages (`sudo apt update` && `sudo apt upgrade`).

Comment: Have you installed it from a .deb file or software ubuntu software store?

Comment: Yes I did it from a .deb file. sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade doesn't work

Comment: I think I have found the solution in this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `refresh` command in snap, to update to the latest vscode version, you can use this command

```
sudo snap refresh --classic code
```

note: you must close all vscode first before running that command

Comment: Worked perfecty, thank you! VSCode 1.75 broke user snippets so needed to update to 1.75.1 which fixed the issue. Above command worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall and reinstall the software using snap store. Softwares installed using `snap` are updated and upgraded automatically in the background. Don't forget to sync your settings before you do that.

```
sudo snap install --classic code
```

Read more about snaps [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/670084/what-you-need-to-know-about-snaps-on-ubuntu-20.04/).